# docker compose communication with container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sidecar

I am trying to create an example to create two WEB API 's and containerize them and to communicate between them.
I would like to see the side car design pattern, I have found an example in Github that I am trying to run.

https://github.com/cesaroll/dotnet-sidecar

In the above example, HelloAPI makes a call to HelloSideCar API which is a different project.
In the HelloAPI a call is made to another API in another project. I am trying to run in local using Docker Compose.

When I try to hit the API from HelloAPI(localhost:8080/FromSidecar) project to SideCarAPI, **I see a 404 error, request is not going to another container
Below Is my Docker Compose**

```
# docker-compose up -d
# docker-compose stop
# docker-compose rm -f

version: '3.8'
services:
  hello-sidecar-api:
    image: hello-sidecar-api:latest
    container_name: hello-sidecar-api
    ports:
      - "8180:8080"

  hello-api:
    image: helloapi:latest
    container_name: hello-api
    environment:
      - SIDERCAR_URL=http://localhost:8180/
    depends_on:
      - hello-sidecar-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: It was my understanding that you can access the other container IF they are on the same network and via `http://container_name:port`. You may need to create a bridged network for it or check the url

Comment: @NanoBit Compose creates a network named `default` for you; you do not typically need explicit `networks:` blocks.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this further.

Comment: What do these two containers do?  What request are you making, to what URL, from where, and what response do you get?  Should the environment variable `SIDECAR_URL` have an extra `R` in it?

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for correcting me there. I've always used a bridged network, so I've never tried the default network. OP, Have you tried accessing http://localhost:8180/ and seeing if you could access it via another app like Postman.

Answer (score 2):

You can either change `SIDECAR_URL` to `http://hello-sidecar-api:8080/` or place both APIs in the same container. Note that I also changed the port from `8180` to `8080`, because `8180` is a port mapped on the host, but inside your Docker network your API is accessible by other containers on `8080`.

Your containers are separate network entities with their own IPs, so when you call `http://localhost:8180` from the inside of a container, you're not calling the host, but the same container from which the request originates. (assuming you're not using `host network driver`).

What you are trying to do here resembles the behavior of pods in Kubernetes (where sidecar term is widely used). In Kubernetes you could put these two containers in one pod and then they could call each other on `localhost`